# Find min value of field in nested array object after aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to find the minimum value of a field in a nested array object after aggregation.

Data example:

```
[
  {
    "id": "i1",
    "version": 1,
    "entries": [
      {
        "name": "n1",
        "position": 1
      }, {
        "name": "n2",
        "position": 2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "i1"
    "version": 2,
    "entries": [
      {
        "name": "n2",
        "position": 3
      }, {
        "name": "n3",
        "position": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "i2",
    "version": 1,
    "entries": [
      {
        "name": "n1",
        "position": 8
      }, {
        "name": "n2",
        "position": 7
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "id": "i2"
    "version": 2,
    "entries": [
      {
        "name": "n2",
        "position": 6
      }, {
        "name": "n3",
        "position": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Pseudo Query:

```
SELECT min(entries["n2"].position) WHERE entries.name="n2" GROUP BY id;
```

Expected Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "i1",
    "min(position)": 2
  }, {
    "id": "i2",
    "min(position)": 6
  }
]
```

I can do this in code, but it's not performant, as I need to return the document sources which can be quite large.

I am thinking of denormalizing the data, but would like to first know if this request is not possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by nesting several aggregations like this:

[terms agg](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) -> [nested agg](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) -> [filter agg](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) -> [min agg](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html)

To test it I set up an index:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "entries": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "position": {
                     "type": "long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "id": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "version": {
               "type": "long"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And indexed your docs:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"id":"i1","version":1,"entries":[{"name":"n1","position":1},{"name":"n2","position":2}]}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"id":"i1","version":2,"entries":[{"name":"n2","position":3},{"name":"n3","position":4}]}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"id":"i2","version":1,"entries":[{"name":"n1","position":8},{"name":"n2","position":7}]}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"id":"i2","version":2,"entries":[{"name":"n2","position":6},{"name":"n3","position":5}]}
```

Here is the query:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "id_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "id"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "nested_entries": {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "entries"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "filter_name": {
                     "filter": {
                        "term": {
                           "entries.name": "n2"
                        }
                     },
                     "aggs": {
                        "min_position": {
                           "min": {
                              "field": "position"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and the result:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "id_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "i1",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "nested_entries": {
                  "doc_count": 4,
                  "filter_name": {
                     "doc_count": 2,
                     "min_position": {
                        "value": 2,
                        "value_as_string": "2.0"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "i2",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "nested_entries": {
                  "doc_count": 4,
                  "filter_name": {
                     "doc_count": 2,
                     "min_position": {
                        "value": 6,
                        "value_as_string": "6.0"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used all together:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/34a013099ef07fb527d9d7cf8490ad1bbafa718b

Comment: the link to the gist is dead